# Could Rhunön Have Made Armor From the Brightsteel?

Tags: inheritance-cycle, christopher-paolini

In *Brisingr*, Rhunön crafts Eragon a sword from an ore of Brightsteel located underneath the Menoa Tree. She told him that that amount was enough to make several swords. Instead of swords, could Rhunön have made Eragon armor along with his sword Brisingr? Maybe Rhunön wasn't specialized in making armor. But Eragon described Brisingr as "light", so the armor may not have been that heavy for him.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

> **Were there shields made of brightsteel, as well?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Maybe. I’d have to think about it. It wouldn’t have been common. It wouldn’t have been common.*
>
> **And what about armor?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Yes, there might have been some chainmail made from brightsteel, but elves don’t really wear plate armor so… maybe some small pieces of armor made from brightsteel.*
>
> <sub>[2019 Books-A-Million Facebook live Q&A](https://www.facebook.com/watch/live/?ref=watch_permalink&v=296363174359606) [48:15 - 48:45]</sub>

> **Did any rider ever choose to wield a weapon other than a sword? Did Rhunon make these weapons? Given that dwarves seem to prefer axes and hammers, would a dwarf rider wield an axe/hammer? Would Rhunon be able to smith it out if Brightsteel for them as a “tool” instead of a “weapon”?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Some Riders did, but it was rather frowned upon, as swords were seen as a more sophisticated/elegant choice than, say, an ax or a spear. Rhunon could make any weapon she wanted out of Brightsteel.*
> <sub>[2023 Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/12yqxp2/im_fantasyscifi_author_christopher_paolini_ask_me/jhpb21z/?context=3)</sub>

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth. Can't argue with that